# Adding to system path

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables, path

I am trying to install the File Checksum Integrity Verifier utility package on my Win 10. downloaded the folder and extracted it into `C:\FCIV` and now I have to add that to my system path. I went to `control panel -> system -> advanced -> Environment Variables` and added `C:\FCIV` to `user variables for owner`.

Then when I start up the command prompt and try to run fciv by typing `fciv.exe/?` as [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841290/availability-and-description-of-the-file-checksum-integrity-verifier-utility) says, I am getting the error telling me that 
fciv.exe is not recognized.

But I can see that the folder FCIV has been added correctly since when I try `cd %FCIV%` from anywhere, I am able to cd into the folder. From there if I try `fciv.exe/?`, I can see that fciv is being recognized.

Am I doing something wrong here? Why is the system not recognizing `fciv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) is used to resolve program names. You should append `;C:\FCIV` to the PATH variable, not create a new variable. `%FCIV%` isn't supposed to work.